# Error- Loading PDF from URL inside android Webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to load the PDF File from URL inside web-view without Downloading in android. Most of the time its loading perfectly ,but sometimes getting below mentioned errors.

**ERROR:1**

```
 ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2787)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:B0F7473971000000] GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : BackFramebuffer::Create: <- error from previous GL command
```

**ERROR:2**

```
validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

**Code Snippet:**

**init()** method called inside On-create

```
private void init()
{
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    PdfWebViewClient pdfWebViewClient = new PdfWebViewClient(this, webview);
    pdfWebViewClient.loadPdfUrl(
                "YOUR URL for Loading PDF");
}
```

**PdfWebViewClient.java**

```
private class PdfWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    private static final String TAG = "PdfWebViewClient";
    private static final String PDF_EXTENSION = ".pdf";
    private static final String PDF_VIEWER_URL = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=";

    private Context mContext;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private boolean isLoadingPdfUrl;

    public PdfWebViewClient(Context context, WebView webView)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mWebView = webView;
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(this);
    }

    public void loadPdfUrl(String url)
    {
        mWebView.stopLoading();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
        {
            isLoadingPdfUrl = isPdfUrl(url);
            if (isLoadingPdfUrl)
            {
                mWebView.clearHistory();
            }

            showProgressDialog();
        }

        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
    {
        return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(url);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
    {
        handleError(errorCode, description.toString(), failingUrl);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request)
    {
        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, uri.toString());
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(final WebView webView, final WebResourceRequest request, final WebResourceError error)
    {
        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        handleError(error.getErrorCode(), error.getDescription().toString(), uri.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading. URL : " + url);
        dismissProgressDialog();
    }

    private boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final String url)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading() URL : " + url);

        if (!isLoadingPdfUrl && isPdfUrl(url))
        {
            mWebView.stopLoading();

            final String pdfUrl = PDF_VIEWER_URL + url;

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    loadPdfUrl(pdfUrl);
                }
            }, 300);

            return true;
        }

        return false; // Load url in the webView itself
    }

    private void handleError(final int errorCode, final String description, final String failingUrl)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error : " + errorCode + ", " + description + " URL : " + failingUrl);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog()
    {
        dismissProgressDialog();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Loading...");
    }

    private void dismissProgressDialog()
    {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean isPdfUrl(String url)
    {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
        {
            url = url.trim();
            int lastIndex = url.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(PDF_EXTENSION);
            if (lastIndex != -1)
            {
                return url.substring(lastIndex).equalsIgnoreCase(PDF_EXTENSION);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant get the error what is going on, but dont use webview for view image or pdf other stuff which is cost too much memory. you better go with native library view to display pdf

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes buffer issues are linked with cache overflow. Try to add `webview.clearCache(true)` to your code.

UPDATE:

```
private void init()
{
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.clearCache(true); // add this string

    PdfWebViewClient pdfWebViewClient = new PdfWebViewClient(this, webview);
    pdfWebViewClient.loadPdfUrl(
            "YOUR URL for Loading PDF");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use [this great library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) for viewing the PDF in your app with URL.

Comment: is it downloading the PDF?

Comment: No, but if you want you can

Comment: @Kumar Wait a minute, I'm sorry for misguiding you it's a library where you can view the PDF which is already present in your device, so first, you need to download  the pdf with that URL and can view it using this library

Comment: @Kumar If you want I can add the code how to download and a file and view it in PDF viewer

Comment: i don't want to download any PDF file into my device,only need load in webveiw from URL

Comment: Above mentioned library will add extra 20Mb to the App